# How do I branch to another use case with extends relationship in an activity diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Sorry to ask another newb question but right now I am translating a UML diagram into an activity diagram. I need to branch my activity diagram to two different use cases each with an extend relationship on the UML chart. What symbol do I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use Call Behavior Action for that.